# TestNG Appium Parallel execution not working

Tags: cucumber, testng, appium

I'm trying to run automated tests in parallel via TestNGCucumberRunner and my problem is that I instantiate my PageObjects with a static get method from my Manager class, as the driver inside it is static. I'm pretty sure this is the problem for the parallel execution. How do I retrieve the driver in a thread-safe way?

Any help is appreciated.

Edit:
My current driver class:

```
public class LocalDriverManager {
    private static ThreadLocal<AppiumDriver> localDriver = new ThreadLocal<>();

    public static AppiumDriver getDriver() {
        return localDriver.get();
    }

    static void setDriver(AppiumDriver driver) {
        localDriver.set(driver);
    }

    public static ThreadLocal<AppiumDriver> getLocalDriver() {
        return localDriver;
    }
}
```

Here I initialize the driver in another class:

This is how I initialize driver and set ThreadLocal in another class:

```
if (capabilities.getPlatform().is(Platform.IOS)) {
            driver = new IOSDriver<MobileElement>(new URL(urlStart + appiumServer.getPort() + "/wd/hub"),
                    capabilities);
        } else {
            driver = new AndroidDriver<MobileElement>(
                    new URL(urlStart + appiumServer.getPort() + "/wd/hub"),
                    capabilities);
        }
        LocalDriverManager.setDriver(driver);
```

I set the localDriver variable when I set my driver in another class and at

```
public BasePage(AppiumDriver driver, WebDriverWait wait) {
        this.driver = driver;
        this.wait = wait;
        PageFactory.initElements(new AppiumFieldDecorator(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(10)), this);
    }
```

I receive this exception now:

```
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set io.appium.java_client.MobileElement field ba.woop.automation.pages.LandingPage.itsBanking to org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$d27c0df4
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:167)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:171)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.set(UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.java:81)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.set(Field.java:780)
        at org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory.proxyFields(PageFactory.java:117)
        at org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory.initElements(PageFactory.java:105)
        at ba.woop.automation.BasePage.<init>(BasePage.java:35)
        at ba.woop.automation.pages.LandingPage.<init>(LandingPage.java:30)
        at ba.klika.automation.steps.LoginCheckSteps.<init>(LoginCheckSteps.java:13)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
        at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjector.newInstance(AbstractInjector.java:145)
        at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector$1.run(ConstructorInjector.java:342)
        at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjector$ThreadLocalCyclicDependencyGuard.observe(AbstractInjector.java:270)
        at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector.getComponentInstance(ConstructorInjector.java:364)
        at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjectionFactory$LifecycleAdapter.getComponentInstance(AbstractInjectionFactory.java:56)
        at org.picocontainer.behaviors.AbstractBehavior.getComponentInstance(AbstractBehavior.java:64)
        at org.picocontainer.behaviors.Stored.getComponentInstance(Stored.java:91)
        at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:699)
        at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:647)
        at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:678)
        at io.cucumber.picocontainer.PicoFactory.getInstance(PicoFactory.java:42)
        at cucumber.runtime.java.ObjectFactoryLoader$ObjectFactoryAdapter.getInstance(ObjectFactoryLoader.java:157)
        at cucumber.runtime.java.JavaStepDefinition.execute(JavaStepDefinition.java:57)
        at cucumber.runner.PickleStepDefinitionMatch.runStep(PickleStepDefinitionMatch.java:50)
        at cucumber.runner.TestStep.executeStep(TestStep.java:65)
        at cucumber.runner.TestStep.run(TestStep.java:50)
        at cucumber.runner.PickleStepTestStep.run(PickleStepTestStep.java:43)
        at cucumber.runner.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:46)
        at cucumber.runner.Runner.runPickle(Runner.java:50)
        at io.cucumber.testng.TestNGCucumberRunner.runScenario(TestNGCucumberRunner.java:79)
        at ba.woop.automation.runners.LoginCheckRunner.runScenario(LoginCheckRunner.java:36)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:124)
        at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:583)
        at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:719)
        at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWithDataProviderMethodWorker.call(TestMethodWithDataProviderMethodWorker.java:71)
        at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWithDataProviderMethodWorker.call(TestMethodWithDataProviderMethodWorker.java:14)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
        at ?.the user clicks on LOGIN button on LANDING PAGE(file:src/test/resources/features/loginCheck.feature:3)
```

Comment: Create a seperate driver manager class and declare driver object as ThreadLocal. You will have to use setter/getter approach to store your threads driver and retrieve it whenever it is required.

Comment: @Sureshmani I tried this approach but it did not work for me. Or should it be a seperate class that only contains driver?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create particular class to store your 'drivers' per thread.

```
public class ThreadLocalDriver {

    private static ThreadLocal<AppiumDriver> tlDriver = new ThreadLocal<>();

    public static ThreadLocal<AppiumDriver> getTlDriver() {
        return tlDriver;
    }

    public static void setTLDriver(AppiumDriver driver) {
            tlDriver.set(driver);
    }
}
```

Once you need to get your driver, just call static method `ThreadLocalDriver.getTlDriver().get();`

Comment: I did exactly this now but I get ` java.lang.IllegalArgumentException` at the first instantiation of a page object in my StepDefinition file

Comment: oh i get it. You need to call `ThreadLocalDriver.getTlDriver().get();` instead of just `ThreadLocalDriver.getTlDriver();`

Comment: that's not the problem, I posted my driver class in the question.

Comment: then you probably using type in your driver, like `AppiumDriver<MobileElement>`. Try to remove generic type and run it one more time.

Comment: I already changed this, but got same error. I added the codesnippet that is the cause of the exception above. It seems initElements method has a problem with this approach

Comment: `this.driver = driver;` paste your local `this.driver` initialization.

Comment: ```protected AppiumDriver<MobileElement> driver;``` I added <MobileElement> again as it makes no difference

Comment: I added initialization as well above

Comment: Firstly. We are trying to fix anther problem that is not related to your question. Your question answered, you can mark the answer as you got what you expected.
Secondly. Try to remove generics during initialization: `driver = new IOSDriver<MobileElement>` to `driver = new IOSDriver`. Or better ask another particular question with this issue.